# Fade out div when click on javascript:history.back()

Tags: html, css, fadein

I've loaded a fadeIn css animation, but when I click the close button the block (naturally) disappears in a flash. Is there a way to reverse the animation when the user clicks the "close"-link (with value javascript:history.back())?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmqg7cyf/)

```
#showme:target {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left; 0;
    background: lightblue;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `javascript:history.back()` at all?

Comment: Long story, I was young and naive, and it just got stuck with me. Kinda realise now how much it sucks. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jquery for the animation part, but I'm unsure as to why you would use this animation with history.back(). The following solution eliminates a lot of extra css as well.

html:

```
<div id="showme" style="display:none;">
    <p>I'm showing</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <a id="show" href="#">Show</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#showme').fadeOut('slow');
});

$('#show').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#showme').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

css:

```
body {margin: 0;}

#showme {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left; 0;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmqg7cyf/4/

Comment: I see. Thanks! The history.back is just a "residue" from an old system that I'd thought would work. One follow-up question: Is there a way to apply this function to a class and open several different #ids (without them opening at the same time...just one by one)?

Comment: @QAW Heres the updated fiddle with what you're looking for: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmqg7cyf/5/).  Is the solution to the previous example acceptable?

Comment: For this task, its preferable to use classes rather than ids so that you can cycle through all the "like" divs.  Also, you can make the divs fadeIn one by one with a delay, as shown in the fiddle that I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done using jQuery fadeOut function.

The first parameter is the duration which is one second in the CSS you wrote.
The second parameter is the callback function that is called after the fade out finishes.

```
$('#showme').fadeOut(duration, function () {
    history.back();
});
```

This line of code should be added on the event handler of the close button click event.

Good Luck